# How to update post meta on wordpress with AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I have the following code:

```
<form method='post'>
<input type='submit' name='bid' value='Licitar'>
```

When the user clicks the submit button, I want to update the WordPress post meta, in order to change the actual bid value.

I'd also like to update, without reloading the page, the following div:

```
<div class='vehicle-value-box'>".auctionplugin_get_latest_bid($post->ID).",00€</div>
```

How can I do both? I have troubles understanding how to capture the $_POST value and use it to do the things above mentioned. Where do I need to put the PHP processing code and include it in WordPress ajax core?

EDIT:

Now my code looks like on page.php (INSIDE THE LOOP, and it is all being "echoed" with PHP):

```
<div id='vehicle-value-box".$post->ID."'>".get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'start_price', true).",00€</div>
 (...)
<div class='vehicle-auction-box'>
<script>
jQuery('input[type=submit]').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: ajaxurl,
         data: 'action=newbid&id=".$post->ID."',
         success: function(msg){
    jQuery('#vehicle-value-box".$post->ID."').html(msg+',00€');
    }
});
</script>
<div>
<form method='post'>
    <input type='submit' name='bid".$post->ID."' value='Licitar' class='bidvalue'>
```

And my functions.php:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_newbid', 'newbid_ajax');
function newbid_ajax() {
    $post_id = $_POST['id'];
    $mybid = get_post_meta($post_id, 'start_price', true);
    $mybid = $mybid + 100;
    update_post_meta($post_id,'start_price',$mybid);
    die($mybid);
}
```

Comment: You might have a loot at [**Updating custom post meta with ajax**](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/108143/updating-custom-post-meta-with-ajax)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit: since you specified in the comment there would be no value input, i edited accordingly.

First thing you would like to make sure that the ajaxurl for wordpress is defined in the front end, for that you can use this code. (insert in functions.php for ex.)

```
add_action('wp_head','my_ajaxurl');
function my_ajaxurl() {
$html = '<script type="text/javascript">';
$html .= 'var ajaxurl = "' . admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) . '"';
$html .= '</script>';
echo $html;
}
```

Secondly, you should create the ajax call, for that add this script tag in the page containing the form :

```
<script>
jQuery('input[type=submit]').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
jQuery.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: ajaxurl,
       data: "action=newbid&id="+<?php echo $post->ID?>,  
       success: function(msg){
            jQuery('.vehicle-value-box').html(msg+",00€");
       }
   });
})
</script>
```

Finally we need to handle the data in wordpress, for that we should use this action in the theme functions.php:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_newbid', 'newbid_ajax');
function newbid_ajax() {
    $post_id = $_POST['id'];

    //Get current bid
    $mybid = get_post_meta($post_id, 'start_price', true);

    //Increase the bid, for example the amount here is 100€
    $mybid = $mybid + 100;

    //Update the database with the increased bid value
    update_post_meta($post_id,'start_price',$mybid);

    // In case you need to update another meta for the user, you 
    // can access the user ID with the get_current_user_id() function

    // Finally sending back the updated bid so the javascript can display it
    die($mybid);
}
```

Comment: I believe I'm missing something because it still doesn't work. Anyway, I might add there are no input values. All I want is when the user clicks on the "BID" button, the value of the auction goes up by, for example, 100€, the user who did it gets recorded and the box with the price is updated.

I'm sure the ajaxurl is now defined. The last piece of code I've tried just to add in the "Do whatever you want" part the following:

update_post_meta('45','start_price',$mybid);

As for the ajax call, the only thing I changed was an hardcoded value for mybidvalue:

var mybidvalue = 100;

Comment: That clarifies a lot more, in your case you don't need to access the bid value in the POST variable, you'll just update the meta key whenever a user clicks on the button. i'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Something is still failing, but I guess the problem is my lack of experience working with AJAX. I have the code in functions.php exactly like the one you posted here. As for the AJAX call, I have it inside the wordpress loop, because I need it for every post on the page. Peraphs if you look at the website you'll see how it's supposed to work. Go to [link](http://standcardeira.com/leiloes/zona-exclusiva/) and look at the button which says "LICITAR". That's where the user clicks. The value above is the one to update and you can use the arrows to navigate between auctions.

Comment: you got two issues, first i added e.preventDefault() in the javascript to stop the page from submitting and use ajax instead. the second problem is the wp_ajax_newbid function is not responding from wordpress. you need to make sure that the function and hook are added to the theme's functions.php , also they need to be the exact same name because we specified that action=newbid in javascript. so make sure that the code from the last step is included correctly.

Comment: Finally something is happening! When I clicked the "LICITAR" button it updated the value with +100 and both auctions "vehicle-value-box", because they both had the same class name. That's not the issue though, I believe I can fix it using something like <div id='vehicle-value-box".$post->ID."'> and jQuery('#vehicle-value-box".$post->ID."').html(msg+',00€'); The problem is: when I click LICITAR on Auction 1, it updates the start_price database value of Auction 2. And when I click "LICITAR" on Auction 2, e.preventDefault() doesn't work and the page is reloaded. Thanks a lot for your help so far!

Comment: I have updated my original post and put there the code how it is right now.

Comment: Another thing I've just found: if I have 3 auctions, I click "LICITAR" on AUCTION 1 and both AUCTION 2 and AUCTION 3 values go up by 100. If I click "LICITAR" on AUCTION 2, only AUCTION 3 value goes up. And if I click "LICITAR" on AUCTION 3, the page reloads and no values are updated.

Comment: hmm interesting, i'll check for more clues